# Understanding Blacklists and Whitelists with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, whitelist

I understand that using a whitelist it only uses everything within that list and with a blacklist it uses everything but what is in the list.

But what happens after that? Say your using a whitelist - can you prevent a submission of an input if what the value of the input contains something that wasn't in the whitelist?

I know that something like this would reduce everything that is not a char or digit with whitespace:

```
preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $stringToFilter );
```

But what if I didnt want the value stored in the database with whitespace. Is there a way to do this so that an error message occurs instead? using if statements for example...

Comment: May you explain a bit more your question?

Comment: Amazing transition from whitelist to whitespace...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that using a whitelist it only uses everything within
>   that list and with a blacklist it uses everything but what is in the
>   list.

- whitelist: items that are approved
- blacklist: items that are *NOT* approved

> preg_replace

You should be using `preg_match` or `filter_var` with the flag `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` instead...more on this below.

> But what if I didnt want the value stored in the database with whitespace. Is there a way to do this so that an error message occurs instead? using if statements for example...

You are talking about validation, so you'd be looking at: [php.net/filter.filters.validate](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate):

```
// false    
var_dump( !filter_var('string with spaces', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/[\s]+/i'))) );

// true
var_dump( !filter_var('string_with_no_spaces', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/[\s]+/i'))) );
```

Wrap the above in an if statement, and you are done.