# Using a whitelist on user input

Tags: php, whitelist

I have a a simple form to login using a username and password. I want to apply a whitelist to allow only certain characters. I dont know if anybody requires this but here is the code to retrieve the username and password:

```
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);      
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

Do I incorporate something like this:

```
preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $stringToFilter );
```

If so, where do I include it within my code? And what happens if a user tries to input something other than what is in the whitelist?

ADDED: Ok well what about if it is during registration and it is using INSERT to store username and password?

```
//insert data
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

//bind the parameters
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
```

Comment: This is probably something you should enforce at registration time, not login time. (Also, you shouldn't need to whitelist the input to a parameterized query that isn't doing insert operations.)

Comment: what's the harm in a user having a hyphen in their user name?

Comment: Why open another question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080682/understanding-blacklists-and-whitelists-with-php)

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);` is wrong. See http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the filtering code before your `INSERT` during registration. Check that the string is not empty after filtering, so that a username of `"!!*&%$#()*&#$"` does not get inserted as a blank string.

```
$username_clean = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $_POST['username'] );

if (!strlen($username_clean)){

    die("username is blank!");
}

$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username_clean, $email_clean, $password_clean);
```

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. How would I do that?

Comment: Updated answer with a rough outline

Comment: One small problem with that code - it works but what if a username of "!!*&bla" was inputted - this would get stored. Is there anyway to workaround that?

Comment: The string that would get stored is `"bla"`. What outcome do you expect/require?